# Strapi put imagefile not changed

Tags: mysql, flutter, postman, strapi

I am using Strapi.

`GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` on strapi works fine.

Uploading files via `POST` works fine.

`PUT` also updates regular fields just fine.

However, when I update an image file, the image hasn't been changed.

the key `data` works fine but the other one didn't work.(It is stored in the Media library.)

[image]

no error occurs either.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the old photo from the university first.

Today I had a similar issue with user profile photos.
The file was uploaded, but the photo was not replaced for the relevant user, and to fix that, I had to remove the photo from the user before I uploaded a new one, which meant two requests one after another.

It's probably best to do it in Strapi directly to avoid making two requests and remove the photo from the storage.

See this answer, it describes the solution pretty well:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/cant-add-image-to-existing-entry-strapi-v4/13331/11